# Weird issue calculating the mean

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the mean value of an array for a monte carlo simulation, but for some reason it gives me a massive number, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing it.

Here is the code

```
void montecarlo()
{
    int arraysize,*ptr, stat=1;
    float randx, avg, stdev,summ=0;

while (stat==1)
    {
        printf("Please Enter the number of simulations to run, between 1,000 and 10,000 without a comma\n");
        scanf("%d",&arraysize);
        if (arraysize<1000 || arraysize>10000)
        {

            printf("Improper array size! \n");
            stat=1;
        }
        else
        {
            stat=0;
        }
    }
        ptr=(int*)calloc(arraysize, sizeof(int));

        for (i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
        {
            random_dimension(2.00, 0.50, &randx );
            printf("%f\n",randx);
            ptr[i]= randx;
            summ+= ptr[i];

        }
        avg=summ/arraysize;
        printf("%f\n",avg);
    srand(time(NULL));
    free(ptr);
}
```

Here is the output where First the random generated values are printed and then the mean is printed (the massive value).
I can't post pictures, but it prints decimal values near 2. the mean calculated is
9414187188170815000000000000.000000
    Here is the random_dimension function:

```
void random_dimension(float nom, float tol, float *random_value)
{

    float r1, r2, r12;
    float sigma = tol / 3;
    do{
    r1 = (float)( rand() % 10001 ) / 10000;
    }while (r1==0);
    r2 = (float)( rand() % 10001 ) / 10000;
    r12 = sqrt(-2*log(r1))*cos(2*M_PI*r2);
    *random_value = nom + sigma * r12;


}
```

Comment: Well, this is insufficient code to solve your problem,please add the whole code!

Comment: Without the declarations of *all* your variables we can't do much.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the variable declarations, and how they are initialized as well.

Comment: Did you initialize `summ` to `0`?

Comment: You need to provide more code.  What is `summ` and **what is it initialized to**?  What's a "massive number"?  What is `randx`?  What does `random_dimension()` do?

Comment: And why are you seeding the random number generator *at the end*, when you're done?

Comment: I got it to give a better value, of 1.534, but I don't see any numbers at or below that value.

Comment: Added Declarations, random_dimension function.

Comment: summ is to add all values in the array, randx is the random generated value

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. What I needed to do was change the dynamic array to a floating type.
Fixed code:

```
int arraysize, stat=1;
    float randx, avg, stdev, *ptr ,summ=0;

    while (stat==1)
    {
        printf("Please Enter the number of simulations to run, between 1,000 and 10,000 without a comma\n");
        scanf("%d",&arraysize);
        if (arraysize<1000 || arraysize>10000)
        {

            printf("Improper array size! \n");
            stat=1;
        }
        else
        {
            stat=0;
        }
    }
        ptr=(float*)calloc(arraysize, sizeof(float));

        srand(time(NULL));
        for (i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
        {
            random_dimension(2.00, 0.50, &randx );
            ptr[i]= randx;
            summ+= ptr[i];
            printf("%f\n",ptr[i]);

        }
        avg=summ/arraysize;
        printf("\n\n%f\n",avg);


    free(ptr);
}
```